# Semantic UI: Auto Initializing Modules Loaded Via AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, module, semantic-ui

Is there a way to have the modules loaded via AJAX? Based on the API documentation, it seems that the only way to make it work is to initialize the module manually after it's loaded into the DOM. I have been writing wrapper classes to manage it so that it works much like how Bootstrap does so developers don't have to worry about initializing them. Did I miss a section in the documentation about this?

Comment: This is still not available in latest release btw. We have decided to drop Semantic UI from our consideration completely since the JavaScript libraries are very unreliable and buggy. Consider using UIKit instead would be my recommendation.